# Oracle Update using a join in the select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to update a field based upon data in a joined table.  I've read that the Update command will not work with a table joins in the where clause.  However, I cannot use the Exists command workaround as my condition is not the existence of a linked record, but rather a value in that linked record.

```
update stock S
set stm_auto_key=186086
From
  STOCK Left Join
  STOCK_RESERVATIONS On STOCK.STR_AUTO_KEY = STOCK_RESERVATIONS.STR_AUTO_KEY
Where
  S.QTY_OH > 0 And
  S.STM_LOT = 128729 And
  STOCK_RESERVATIONS.IND_AUTO_KEY Is Null
```

The select statement works fine stand alone. However using it in an update command yields "SQL command not properly ended."

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You have `JOIN` in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with your sql? Can you please post more information about structure your tables and desirable result.

Comment: Try update stock s set stm_auto_key=186086  where S.QTY_OH > 0 And
  S.STM_LOT = 128729 And s.STR_AUTO_KEY in (select STR_AUTO_KEY from STOCK_RESERVATIONS sr where sr.IND_AUTO_KEY Is Null);

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need something like this, because there might be no FROM clause in UPDATE statement:

```
update stock S
set stm_auto_key=186086
Where
  S.QTY_OH > 0 And
  S.STM_LOT = 128729 And
  (SELECT STOCK_RESERVATIONS.IND_AUTO_KEY FROM STOCK_RESERVATIONS
   WHERE S.STR_AUTO_KEY = STOCK_RESERVATIONS.STR_AUTO_KEY) Is Null
```

Comment: Perfect!  Sometimes the best solutions are the simplest. Thank you very much.